# Kusto | Summarize count() multiple columns with where clauses

Tags: azure-data-explorer, kql

I'm trying to get the count of multiple things in a Kusto query but having trouble getting it working. Let's say I have a sample table like this:

```
let SampleTable = datatable(Department:string, Status:string, DateStamp:datetime) 
[
   "Logistics", "Open", "05-01-2019",
   "Finance", "Closed", "05-01-2020",
   "Logistics", "Open", "05-01-2020"
];
```

And I query like this:

```
SampleTable
| summarize closedEntries = count() by (Status | where Status == "Closed"), 
    openEntries = (Status | where Status == "Open"),
    recentDates = (DateStamp | where DateStamp > "12-31-2019"),
    Department
```

Expected results:

[image: expected results]

But this gives an error "The name 'Status' does not refer to any known column, table, variable or function." and the same error for DateStamp. I've also tried using extend and join but it's a mess.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

you could use the `countif()` aggregation function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/countif-aggfunction

```
datatable(Department:string, Status:string, DateStamp:datetime) 
[
   "Logistics", "Open", "05-01-2019",
   "Finance", "Closed", "05-01-2020",
   "Logistics", "Open", "05-01-2020"
]
| summarize closedEntries = countif(Status == "Closed"),
            openEntries = countif(Status == "Open"),
            recentDates = countif(DateStamp > datetime(12-31-2019))
         by Department
```